# FireBase, simultaneous connections?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an Android App working with Firebase Real Time Database, I've read that only 100 simultaneous connections are allowed , but what happens when the 101th device try to connect to FireBase? Any excepetion is thrown?

Comment: As I read in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore?authuser=0) **today** Realtime Database: "Scale to around 200,000 concurrent connections and 1,000 writes/second in a single database. Scaling beyond that requires sharding your data across multiple databases."

Answer (score 1):

When 101th simultaneous connection occurs, Firebase will wait until one connection is closed and only when a connection is closed it will use your new connection.

Keep in mind that you'll don't have a temporarily shut down until you upgrade your pricing plan. Your database will still work for sure.

Comment: Okay, but do you think that any exception is thrown? Try { }catch is required to avoid app crashes ?

Comment: A simultaneous connection is equivalent to one mobile device, browser tab, or server app connected to the database. The reason those 100 simultaneous connections exists, is to protect Firebase servers from abuse. As i said above, your database won't be affected, your app won't crash when 101th connection occurs and you won't be notified explicitly. Firebase engineers encourage you to monitor your peak simultaneous database connections and upgrade or add more databases if needed.

Comment: An important thing that you can do is to add a `OnCompleteListener` and than you can measure the time between you start the operation and the time it complets. If the time goes up, than most likely you're being buffered.