# FireBase Simultaneous connections

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so i read this thread : [FireBase, simultaneous connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154897/firebase-simultaneous-connections)

And the answer it got is :

> When 101th simultaneous connection occurs than Firebase waits until
>   one connection is closed, and than it uses your new connection.
>
> Keep in mind that you'll don't have a temporarily shut down until you
>   upgrade your pricing plan. Your database will still work for sure.
>
> Hope it helps.

So now what i want to do using the Firebase real time database is,
when the app runs, it should get the data from the database (JUST ONCE) so i'll use ValueEventListener right ? and then i want to close the connection so some other user when he opens the app, gets the connection.

So basically the connection should open when the user opens the app and it should close as soon as all the data is recieved. So how am i supposed to do this ?

Comment: As I read in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore?authuser=0) **today** Realtime Database: "Scale to around 200,000 concurrent connections and 1,000 writes/second in a single database. Scaling beyond that requires sharding your data across multiple databases."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stop the SDK from establishing and maintaining an open connection, call the [goOffline()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#goOffline()) method of FirebaseDatabase() after you're done with the connection:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline();
```

This will stop the app from connected while it's running.  However, this will not stop the app from reconnecting if it's killed and relaunched.  You will have to keep calling this method with every launch after you are done with the connection.